# How do I send input to url using form without Php? (form action)

Tags: php, forms

I want to send this query (**EA452401760IN**) to `https://track.aftership.com/india-post/`.

After a successful submission by Form the URL will be 
`https://track.aftership.com/india-post/EA452401760IN`

**Form**

```
<form method="POST" action="https://track.aftership.com/india-post/" target="_blank"> <input type="text" value="EA452401760IN"></input><button type="submit"> submitc</button></form>
```

Do I need a PHP file for this?

If yes, how do I write a php file for this problem.

Comment: Did you tried it with javascript?

Comment: You should be using their API to do such thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure Javascript approach with Jquery

```
<input type="text" id="trackingNumber" value="EA452401760IN"></input>

<button onclick="go()">Track</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script>
    $( "button" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
        window.location.href = "https://track.aftership.com/india-post/" + $('#trackingNumber').val();
    });
</script>
```

JSBIN: https://jsbin.com/fuqovocoza/edit?html,console,output

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")){
//Check that the form has been posted if it has been then redirect to the correct page
header ('Location: https://track.aftership.com/india-post/' . $_POST['query']);
}
else
{
 if the form has not been submitted display the form
<form method="POST" action="https://track.aftership.com/india-post/" target="_blank"> <input type="text" name="query" value="EA452401760IN"></input><button type="submit"> submitc</button></form>
```

Note that I have changed the name of the input field to query.